# WebApi read URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webforms

I am writing web api, I am sending data to this api, It is a post method,its content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded,content encoding is UTF-8,

URL is  http://www.example.com/GetProcess.aspx

data is ApiKey=xxxxxxx&Gsm=5055555555&Date=30.04.2015&Process=block

above is example , How can I retrieve data that is requested?

below is sample request to api but how can i retrieve this request in api

```
$.ajax({
                url: http://www.example.com/GetProcess.aspx,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function(data) {
                },
                error: function(error) {

                }
        });
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: please post some code

Comment: I do not see Web API. Do you mean Web Service?

Comment: It will be a simple web form, it will read request from url and response write to page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Request.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the posted data.

For example,

```
var apiKey = Request.Form["ApiKey"];
```

***FYI:*** You cannot return Json from Web Form. If you want, you want to use [Web Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx).